# ag-Grid onCellEditingStopped event does not provide previous value

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, vue.js, ag-grid

I am using ag-Grid **onCellEditingStopped** event handler to get the changed value of a grid cell.

```
onCellEditingStopped: function(event) {
    // event.value present the current cell value
    console.log('cellEditingStopped');
}
```

But it does not provide the previous value (the value before the change happens). Is there anyway to get the previous value ?

My current solution:

I am using **onCellEditingStarted** event to store the current cell value in a separate variable and use that variable inside the **onCellEditingStopped** event handler function. But it is not a clear solution.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that's the only way =).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use value Setter function for that column as below.

```
    valueSetter: function (params) {

       console.log(params.oldValue);

       console.log(params.newValue);

       if (params.oldValue !== params.newValue) {
           //params.data["comments"] = params.newValue;
           return true;
       }
       else {
           return false;
       }
    }
```

Comment: params.data["fieldName"] = params.newValue; this line is essential for the code to be working. Otherwise old value is assigned again as the new value even though "return true" statement exists

Comment: @tnishada to get it dynamically u need this line : params.data[params.colDef.field]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `onCellEditingStopped` in my Angular application, with agGrid v24.1... and it does have an `oldValue` and a `newValue` value in there.

```
onCellEditingStopped = (_params) => {
  if (_params.newValue != _params.oldValue) {
    //  Do something...
  }
}
```